# Containerd ctr command for pulling images gives error

Tags: windows-container, shim, containerd

I am new to containerd and I am trying to run the windows containers using containerd. After installing containerd, I just tried to pull the image from registry and I got below issue. The issue i am getting is from the container runtime hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer method while processing the image. Kindly help me on solving the issue. I am using containerd 1.6.0-rc.1 (Pre-release). I am using this since I want to try out Windows HostProcess Containers. PFB the issue.

```
PS C:\Program Files\containerd> .\crictl.exe pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:20H2
time="2022-01-21T07:29:44Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:20H2\": failed to extract layer sha256:4370934b39e53babdf58bfe6ff2bcc662e068d3b71bd015ea280a402a89e6673: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\containerd\\root\\io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.windows\\snapshots\\12: The specified module could not be found.: unknown"
```